# Collect temp values in other functions

Tags: php, symfony, logging, design-patterns, dependency-injection

I develop the application with Symfony framework ( use Dependency Injection), assuming that I have three services:

```
<?php

class ServiceA 
{
    public function funcInServiceA($input) 
    {
        $result = 'something';
        $tempValueA = $input + 'something';
        return $result;
    }
}


class ServiceB
{
    public function funcInServiceB($input) 
    {
        $result = 'something';
        $tempValueB = $input + 'something';
        return $result;
    }
}

class ServiceC
{
    public function funcInServiceC()
    {
        $resultFromA = $this->serviceA->funcInServiceA('input');
        $resultFromB = $this->serviceB->funcInServiceB($resultFromA);
        return $resultFromB;
    }
}
```

I need to collect `$tempValueA, $tempValueB, $resultFromA, $resultFromB` for logging, Is there any design pattern or best practice to do that?

Regards,

Comment: design pattern could be decorator pattern, but psr-3 looks promising too: https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-3/ (your services could implement the LoggerAwareInterface and log if a logger is set) but you can also specifically get a LoggerInterface from symfony in your service's constructor. actually logging input/output is obviously *explicit*. however, your question *is* still opinion-based.

Comment: Thank you @Jakumi. More detail about my question,  I want to store `$tempValueA, $tempValueB, $resultFromA, $resultFromB` in one record on DB ( I use doctrine).

Comment: If I create `entity` and save `$tempValueA` on it, I have to pass it to `funcInServiceB()` and `funcInServiceC()` for updating new item. So I need they way to collect all data, and save them to entity once time.

Comment: I would think, that instead of a simple and scalar `$input`, you would have to upgrade to a structured job object/array and write temporary results to it. Injecting something into every service as Domagoj suggested will make it hard to distinguish between jobs if code runs in parallel or if services can be used in any order. Logging temporary values that are spread all over the place are hard to handle ;o/

Answer (score 1):

1. Create `ServiceD` and inject EntityManager in it.
2. Create class variable there, say `values` and function to store temp values to this class variable.
3. Inject `ServiceD` in every other `Service(A|B|C)` from where you need to store temp values.
4. Call the ServiceD's function that stores temp values to class variable.
5. Persist `values` - how to call this depends on your current design - without any further info, I'd say subscribe to kernel event that suits your needs best.